# Rails - "Cannot find object with 'id'="

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms

I hope someone can help me sort this out. I'm creating a nested_form_for Order.new, with fields_for DateOrder.new.

In my orders_controller, I have defined @school in the 'new' and 'create' actions, which is important for both order/new and order/show. Yet, Rails doesn't seem to find a School with the parameters.

Error when I submit the form: **ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in OrdersController#create**

(Couldn't find School with 'id'=)

PARAMETERS: "order"=>{"user_id"=>"2",
 "school_id"=>"1", ... } <-- seems fine to me, :school_id = 1.

Routes.rb

```
get '/schools/:school_id/orders/new' => 'orders#new'

resources :schools do
  resources :orders
end
resources :orders
```

Orders_controller.rb

```
def new
    @order = Order.new
    @order.date_orders.build
    @school = School.find(params[:school_id])
end

def create
    @school = School.find(params[:school_id])
    @order = Order.new(order_params)
    if @order.save
        flash[:success] = "Thank you for your request. We will get in touch with you shortly."
        render @order
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end

def show
    @order = Order.find(params[:id])
    @user = current_user
    if current_user && current_user.school_manager
      @school = School.find(SchoolAdmin.find_by(user_id: current_user.id).school_id)
    elsif current_user && current_user.district_manager
      @district = District.find(DistrictAdmin.find_by(user_id: current_user.id).district_id)
    end
end
```

Orders/new.html.erb

```
<%= nested_form_for @order do |f| %>

  <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :school_id, :value => params[:school_id] %>
  # SOME MORE FIELDS #
  <%= f.fields_for :date_orders do |builder| %>
    # SOME FIELDS_FOR #
  <% end %>

<% end %>
```

here are my logs:

```
    Started POST "/orders" for 174.116.225.174 at 2016-05-06 18:53:52 +0000
Processing by OrdersController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"X2mZC7JqEPdygS5vL5Y5ecOEkEdSCoGT6EHhPIIAqqKQlsV4z9xJD4sqhlH3fO5FeO+Ds7T4CWynZCYmhF+ayA==", "order"=>{"user_id"=>"2", "school_id"=>"1", "district_id"=>"1", "facility_school_id"=>"1", "date_orders_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"_destroy"=>"false", "order_date"=>"", "time_start"=>"", "time_end"=>""}}, "purpose"=>"Meeting or workshop", "attendees"=>"Mission High School students", "attendees_number"=>"", "description"=>"", "full_name"=>"", "user_group"=>"Mission High School student", "email"=>"", "phone_number"=>"", "occupation"=>""}, "commit"=>"Request to book"}
  School Load (1.4ms)  SELECT  "schools".* FROM "schools" WHERE "schools"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", nil]]
Completed 404 Not Found in 3ms (ActiveRecord: 1.4ms)

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find School with 'id'=):
  app/controllers/orders_controller.rb:13:in `create'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just solved for the issue.

As the two kind commenters pointed out, I started off with :school_id in the params, and my create action had :school_id inside an :order param. When I redirected a flawed attempt to create an :order, Rails couldn't find a School with the id. While neither of their solutions worked for me, they helped me find a solution.

how I solved it:

```
def create
    @order = Order.new(order_params)
    @school = School.find(@order.school_id)
    if @order.save
        flash[:success] = "Thank you for your request. We will get in touch with you shortly."
        render @order
    else
        **redirect_to "/schools/#{@school.id}/orders/new"**
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In the query, you're passing in 2 values:
`SELECT  "schools".* FROM "schools" WHERE "schools"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", nil]]`
The error is saying there is no school where `school.id = 'id='`.

I think what you have to do is associate the `@school` to `@order` explicitly.

In the create function, add:

```
@school = School.find(params[:school_id])
@order = Order.new(order_params)
@order.school = @school
if @order.save
....
```

You may also need to remove the school_id from order_params before constructing the `@order`.

Comment: Nope, this is what I get in the logs: Started GET "/schools/1/orders/new" for 174.116.225.174 at 2016-05-06 19:16:00 +0000
Processing by OrdersController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"school_id"=>"1"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 43ms (ActiveRecord: 3.1ms)

NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass):
  app/controllers/orders_controller.rb:9:in `new'

Comment: @GuilhermeNazarethdeSouza, yea I looked through again, I was def wrong!

Answer (score 0):

In the `params` hash, `school_id` is nested under the `order` key, so you would need to access it with `params[:order][:school_id]`. As it is now, `params[:school_id]` will return `nil`, which is why you're getting that error message that doesn't actually have an ID.

Your params:

```
Parameters: {
    "utf8"=>"✓",
    "authenticity_token"=>"X2mZC7JqEPdygS5vL5Y5ecOEkEdSCoGT6EHhPIIAqqKQlsV4z9xJD4sqhlH3fO5FeO+Ds7T4CWynZCYmhF+ayA==",
    "order"=>{
      "user_id"=>"2",
      "school_id"=>"1",
      "district_id"=>"1",
      "facility_school_id"=>"1",
      "date_orders_attributes"=>{
        "0"=>{"_destroy"=>"false", "order_date"=>"", "time_start"=>"", "time_end"=>""}},
      "purpose"=>"Meeting or workshop",
      "attendees"=>"Mission High School students",
      "attendees_number"=>"",
      "description"=>"",
      "full_name"=>"",
      "user_group"=>"Mission High School student",
      "email"=>"",
      "phone_number"=>"",
      "occupation"=>""},
      "commit"=>"Request to book"
  }
```

Note that `school_id` is nested under `order`. This cannot be accessed with `params[:school_id`].

**EDIT**

So now it sounds like from your comments that when `create` is fixed by changing it to `params[:order][:school_id]`, you get an error in the `new` action.

Backing up a bit, you only need to change it to `params[:order][:school_id]` *in the `create` action*. For the `new` action, you would leave it as `params[:school_id]`.

Comment: Doesnt work either: Started GET "/schools/1/orders/new" for 174.116.225.174 at 2016-05-06 19:16:00 +0000 Processing by OrdersController#new as HTML Parameters: {"school_id"=>"1"} Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 43ms (ActiveRecord: 3.1ms) NoMethodError (undefined method []' for nil:NilClass): app/controllers/orders_controller.rb:9:in new' –

Comment: That is a different error. My answer is for the question you originally asked. If you look back at your original question and the `params` hash you provided, `:school_id` is clearly nested under `:order`. If you are now getting a different error, then your code has multiple problems that need to be addressed. What is on line 9 that is trying to use `[]`? Can you post your entire controller in the original question?

Comment: Oh, I meant same error that I got with Joe Essey's suggestion right above this. And I tried your solution before, too. Let me gather some more information for you, and thanks for the help :)

Comment: Line 9 is "@school = School.find(params[:order][:school_id])" in def new.

Comment: @GuilhermeNazarethdeSouza the reason *that one* doesn't work is because the params are now just `{school_id: 1}` (Parameters: {"school_id"=>"1"}). So of course at that time there is now no `order` node above `school_id`, and when it does `params[:order]` that is returning `nil`, which won't work with `[:school_id]`. You need to have `params[:order][:school_id]`, but send params that look like the original (longer) ones.

Comment: @GuilhermeNazarethdeSouza so it seems like the reason it's breaking is because you need to access `school_id` differently depending on which controller action you're in. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Still not working: ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find School with 'id'=):
  app/views/orders/new.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_orders_new_html_erb__3171472428827856586_70156082279500'
  app/controllers/orders_controller.rb:19:in `create'

Comment: do you have any other insight that might help?